# I don't understand how to go at this specific loop issue everytime I try a loop I System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am creating a program and I need help on how I should go at this I need it to read encoded letters and return the correct letter but any loop that I try I just get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException and it says that I need to make sure that what I am calling is just as long as what is there.

```
Private Sub btnDecode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDecode.Click
    Do While ((y / 4) = txtDecoded.Text.Length)
        If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "1" Then
            y = y + 1
            If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "0" Then
                y = y + 1
                If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "1" Then
                    y = y + 2
                    strholder2(z) = "S"
                ElseIf txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "0" Then
                    y = y + 2
                    strholder2(z) = "s"
                End If
            Else
                If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "5" Then
                    y = y + 1
                    If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "9" Then
                        y = y + 2
                        strholder2(z) = "O"
                    Else
                        If txtEncoded.Text.Substring(y, 1) = "8" Then
                            y = y + 2
                            strholder2(z) = "o"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Dim h As Integer
    For h = 0 To (z)
        strencode2 = strencode2 & strholder2(z)
    Next
    txtDecoded.Text = strencode2
    Label1.Text = y.ToString
End Sub
```

Now that I took Francis Lord's loop into account I figured out how to get it working so thank you Francis Lord and everyone that gave me feedback..[image]

Comment: You might want to add some punctuation, too.  And identify *where* the exception occurs.

Comment: You also need to copy the error message and paste it in your question; do not attempt to summarize the message.

Comment: *Here's a big dump of my code, with some vague description of some error I get, and no idea where it's happening. Debug it for me.* isn't going to work. You get a specific error message that tells you exactly what the problem is and what line it's on, and it's right on the screen in front of you. There is absolutely no reason for you not to give that information to us. Create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, include the **exact** error message you get and the line it happens on, and we might be able to help. While you're making that [edit], add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: There are 4 loops in your code. I'll take a guess, is it the third loop? Ok I give up. What's the answer?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you have a `Do While()` loop, keep adding 1 to `y` and looping, and never add a condition to stop when you reach the limit of the array? The Code Fairy to jump in and stop the loop with magic? Do you expect `SubString(y, 1)` to keep working while `y` gets larger and larger until `SubString` gets tired?

Comment: no I took out the loop I don't know how to limit the amount of times it runs the loop I'm not stupid

Comment: Fix your question or you'll find that it will accrue the required number of requests to be closed very soon. Post ONLY the RELEVANT code. Provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the issue, including the EXACT error message and the EXACT location that the exception is thrown.  Also, have you actually checked what index is being used at the time and what the valid range is?  If not, why not?  If so, why haven't you told us what they are?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a condition in your While loop to stop it from incrementing the `y` past the length of your string. Something like

```
Do While(y < txtEncode.Text.Lenght)
```

would do, but I'm not too sure how your code is supposed to work so you might have to adjust the condition to match your logic.